# Unable to retrieve Json error messages from response in Ajax error handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have an ajax request that has an error handler that outputs the errormessages returned in a json response like this:
(Ignore the second for loop I'm just showing what I tried already, the part that should have worked afaik was the alert(error) or alert(error.msg) in the first for loop):

```
error: function(xhr){
                    var error_array = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                    for (var error in error_array){
                        for (var err in error){                        
                            alert(err);
                        }   
                        //alert(error['msg'];
                        //alert(error.msg);
                        //alert(error);
                    }

                }
```

The json that is being returned by my controller is structured like this:
[image]

The only values so far I have been able to get out of this response are 0 and 1 when using alert(error) and undefined when I do anything else, can anyone help me with getting these error messages from the response in my javascript function?

EDIT: if I do `alert(error_array)` I get my 2 strings separated by a comma

Comment: The Javascript "for" doesn't work the way you think. "error" and "err" are the keys, not the array values. You should use error_array[error] and error_array[error][err]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment and answer posted weren't exactly what I was looking for but pushed me into the right direction to find the proper way to get my error messages, this is how I got it to work:

```
error: function(xhr){
                var error_array = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                for (error in error_array){
                    alert(error_array[error].msg);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're alerting object key, not a value.
To get a value you should:

```
alert(error[err]);
```